# fadeout on mouseout using keyframes?

Tags: css, fadeout

I'm using keyframes animation and I'm using markers that when you hover over them, information or a picture will appear.  I added a fade-in, but I don't know how to get it to fade out.
I have the keyframes part:

```
@keyframes fadeout {
0% {
  opacity: 1;}
100% {opacity: 0;}
}
.fadeout {
-webkit-animation-name: fadeout;
animation-name: fadeout;
}
```

And this is the animation part (?) I want to insert:

```
animation-duration: 0.5s;
animation-name: fadeout;
```

I guess my problem is that I don't know how to insert it.

This is the codepen I'm using:

http://codepen.io/aslenwhitmore/pen/rxLYgQ?editors=0100

so can anyone tell me where I should insert the fadeout?
thanks!

Comment: This is probably best approached by using class toggle transition instead of animation IMO.

Comment: @Aziz I think I'm trying to avoid using JQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve your desired effect by using `transition` property which triggers an opacity state on hover. There is no need of javascript since CSS allows you to manipulate children of selector on hover or other states.

[See my codepen fork for a working example](http://codepen.io/azizn/pen/YwLgwQ?editors=1100)

Since CSS cannot transition the `display` property, we'll just use opacity and `z-index`.

The `z-index` will hide the elements under the document (`z-index:-1`) and bring them to 999 once activated

**Hover Code**

```
&:hover .map-marker-info {
    opacity:1;
    z-index:999;
}
```

**Static Code**

```
&-marker-info {
   display: block;
   transition:0.3s;
   opacity: 0;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

P.S I recommend to increase the radius of the hover zone to make the points more user friendly

Comment: glad I could help. go ahead and accept my answer with the check mark under the votes count. have a nice day

Comment: It mostly worked, but now on the fadeout I realized it moves to the left. http://codepen.io/aslenwhitmore/pen/rxLYgQ?editors=0100

Comment: Make sure to have `text-align:center` as a base style instead of hover style

Answer (score 0):

Just change your animation into a transition.

Set your information popup's opacity to 0. Then set it's `:hover` opacity to 1. Now change the `animation: fade-in 1s` bit to `transition: opacity 1s`.